# Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-authentication

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

  const responseGoogle = (response) => {

    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));

    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;

    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };

    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate('/', { replace: true });
    });
  };
```

I get an error that "name is undefined" – but how? `imageUrl` and `googleId` are working fine, so what's the problem with `name`?

Comment: Can you share your response Object It will be helpful

Comment: how can i share that @FaisalAhmed

Comment: I doubt that `googleId`, `imageUrl` are "working fine". You are just getting the error for name only because it's the first property it tries to destructure and it already fails there.  This error message tells you that `response.profileObj` is `undefined` thus cannot be destructured ...

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are working on the ShareMe Project from (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxXyfkrP298&t=3800s) as I am.

Thing is login was updated and now Google's service returns a different set of parameterss in their response than what used to be returned when the video was recorded.

The parameters you're looking for like "name" and "id" are now found within response.credential, but it is encoded (for security reasons) now you have to decode it. You will have to install 'jwt-decode' within 'shareme_frontend' folder with "npm i jwt-decode" () and you will be able to use "var decodedHeader = jwt_decode(response.credential);" to decode it, and you should be able to work with properties "name", "sub" instead of ID, and "picture", this should get you up to speed.

The issue you experience is coming as name being undefined because there is no response.name, but only response.credential.name and needs decoding. So it can be very frustrating but you'll see the issue when you print ressponse.

sources:

- JWT https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode
- 'sub'property in response.credential: https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect

My example:

```js
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";


const responseGoogle=(response)=>{
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
    var decodedHeader = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    console.log(decodedHeader);

    const { name, sub, picture } = decodedHeader;

    const doc = {
      _id: sub,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: picture,
    }

    client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      .then(() =>{
        navigate('/', { replace: true })
      })

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's probably a notation issue, try this instead:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const responseGoogle = (response) => {

localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));

const doc = {
  _id: response.profileObj.googleId,
  _type: 'user',
  userName: response.profileObj.name,
  image: response.profileObj.imageUrl,
};

client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
  navigate('/', { replace: true });
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Update: React updated their login method, so you need to search for the most up to date google login method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
npm install gapi-script
```

then add useEffect function like this

```
useEffect(() => {
function start() {
  gapi.client.init({
    ClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN,
    scope: '',
  })
}
gapi.load('client:auth2', start)})
```

Comment: Could fix indentation so it's more clear. Also, dependancy array missing in useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem with the same question, is this one the shareme project? And I think googleId and imageUrl also not work. You can switch the order of these three like

```
const {  imageUrl,name, googleId } = response.profileObj;
```

And it will give you the error:
cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs:225 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'imageUrl' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined.

So, I also stuck here and seeking for help!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since this question but I found a solution that worked for me, I made changes to the call this way

```
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response));
    const { clientId, name, imageUrl } = response;
    const doc = {
      _id: clientId,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };
    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate('/', { replace: true });
    });
  };
```

I also changed the google button library, used **@react-oauth/google** and the button looked like this:

```
<GoogleLogin
   onSuccess={responseGoogle}
   onError={responseGoogle}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I been figuring out for this for a while , turns out there's a different method for the same thing.(React keeps updating the google login method so an updated method is required),
In the response object a credential attribute was there, it needs to be decoded by the **jwt_decode** function , which can be imported from the library '**jwt-decode**' on which furhter the details can be extracted .

```
const responseGoogle = (response) =>{
    console.log(response);
    var profileObj = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    console.log(profileObj);
    const doc = {
      _id: profileObj.sub,
      _type: "user",
      userName: profileObj.name,
      image: profileObj.picture,
      };
    client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      .then(()=>{
        console.log('Login Created')
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should look like this:

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";    

const responseGoogle = (response) =>{
    console.log(response);
    var profileObj = jwt_decode(response.credential);
    console.log(profileObj);
    const doc = {
        _id: profileObj.sub,
        _type: "user",
        userName: profileObj.name,
        image: profileObj.picture
    };

    console.log(doc)
    client.createIfNotExists(doc)
          .then(()=>{
              navigate("/", { replace: true });
              console.log('Login Created')
          }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a new update, we use Google Identity Services SDK check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google .

Try this code for login and getting the user information.

Login.jsx :

```
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { GoogleLogin, googleLogout } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import {FcGoogle} from 'react-icons/fc' ;
import shareVideo from '../assets/share.mp4' ;
import logo from '../assets/mejlis-logo.png' ;
import {client} from '../client';
import jwt_decode  from "jwt-decode";
//import JWT from 'google-auth-library';
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = async(response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(response);
    const decoded = jwt_decode(response.credential)
    const { sub, name, picture } = decoded;
    const doc = {
      _id: sub,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: picture,
    };
    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate('/', { replace: true });
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen'>
      <div className='relativr w-full h-full'>
        <video src ={shareVideo} type ='video/mp4'
        loop
        controls={false}
        muted
        autoPlay
        className='w-full h-full object-cover' />
      </div>
      <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right- left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
        <div className='p=5'>
          <img  src={logo} width="130px" alt='logo'/>
        </div>
        <div className='shadow-2x1'>
          <GoogleOAuthProvider
          clientId={`${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}`}>
            <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
            onFailure={responseGoogle}
            cookiePolicy = 'single_host_origin' />
          </GoogleOAuthProvider>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue created for google updated their Google sign in setup. You can try this code after installing the latest Google OAuth:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
    
const responseGoogle = (response) => {
  const decoded = jwt_decode(response.credential);
  console.log(decoded);
    
  const { name, picture, sub } = decoded;
    
  const user = {
    _id: sub,
    _type: 'user',
    userName: name,
    image: picture
  };

  client.createIfNotExists(user)
    .then(()=>{
      navigate('/', { replace: true });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As multiple people pointed out before me, this error is occurring both due to a different structure in the new response from Google and also the fact that the proposed React library for the Google Login from the tutorial video is deprecated. This is an up-to-date way to solve the issue:

First, update the library you are using for the Google login. For this, run in the terminal:

```
npm uninstall react-google-login
```

Then, install the currently most up-to-date library [React OAuth2 | Google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google). Follow the steps on their npm page (see the link before) to install this library. In the particular case of this tutorial, the steps are these:

(1) Install the new library

```
npm install @react-oauth/google@latest
```

(2) Wrap your application with GoogleOAuthProvider. Your App.js file should look somewhat like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from "@react-oauth/google";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Home from "./container/Home";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

(3) Change the code in your Login.jsx file, to reflect both the change of the library used and the change in the response structure. It should look somewhat like this:

```
import { GoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";
const responseGoogle = (response) => {
 localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
 const decodedHeader = jwt_decode(response.credential);
 
 const { name, sub, picture } = decodedHeader;
 const doc = {
   _id: sub,
   _type: "user",
   userName: name,
   image: picture,
 };
 
 client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
   navigate("/", { replace: true });
 });
};
```

For future changes in the response or the libraries used, try to console log the Google response itself. In my case, the errors were pretty accurate in telling me what to do to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that using 'aud' would not work properly.  Instead use sub for correctly passing different googleIDs.

Here is my source code atleast.

```
    import React from 'react'
// import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login'
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { GoogleLogin, googleLogout } from '@react-oauth/google'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import shareVideo from '../assets/share.mp4'
import logo from '../assets/LogoSWhite2.png'

import {client} from '../client'


const Login = () => {

    // const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    //     console.log(response);
    //   }
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
      const decode = jwt_decode(response.credential);
      console.log(decode);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(decode));
        const { name, sub, picture } = decode;

        const doc = {
          _id: sub, 
          _type: 'user',
          userName: name,
          image: picture,
        }

        console.log("googleId:", sub);
        console.log("image:", picture);



        client.createIfNotExists(doc)
        .then(() => {
            navigate('/', {replace: true})
        })
    }

  return (
    <div className="flex justiy-start items-center flex-col h-screen">
      <div className="relative w-full h-full">
        <video
            src={shareVideo}
            type="video/mp4"
            loop
            controls={false}
            muted
            autoPlay
            className='w-full h-full object-cover'
        />

        <div className='absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay'>
        <div className="p-5">
        <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" />
        </div>

        <div className='shadow-2xl'>
        <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}>
          <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
            onFailure={responseGoogle}
            cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
          />
        </GoogleOAuthProvider>


            {/* <GoogleOAuthProvider
             clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}>
              <GoogleLogin
             render={(renderProps) => (
                <button
                type="button"
                className="bg-mainColor flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none"
                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                >
                    <FcGoogle className="mr-4"/> Sign in with Google

                </button>

             )}
            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
            onFailure={responseGoogle}
            cookiePolicy="single_host_origin"
            
            />;
            </GoogleOAuthProvider>; */}
            


        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```