# Google OAuth not directing to home page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, google-api, google-oauth

I am setting up a login page using google OAuth in react, I am following a youtube tutorial, everything seems to work fine but somehow after logging in, I am not being redirected to my homepage. here is the code (Login.jsx):

```
import React from 'react'
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FcGoogle } from 'react-icons/fc';
import carVideo from '../assets/car.mp4';
import logo from '../assets/speedograph white.png';
import { client } from '../client';


const Login = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
    if (response.profileObj) {
      const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;
    
      const doc = {
        _id: googleId,
        _type: 'user',
        userName: name,
        image: imageUrl,
      };
      client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
        navigate('/', { replace: true });
      });
  }
};

  return (
    <div className = "flex justify-start items-center flex-col h-screen">
      <div className='relative w-full h-full'>
        <video 
          src={carVideo}
          type='video/mp4'
          loop
          controls={false}
          muted
          autoPlay
          className='w-full h-full object-cover'
        />
        <div className = "absolute flex flex-col justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay">
          <div className="p-5 ml-3">
            <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" />
          </div>
          <div className='shadow-2xl'>
            <GoogleLogin
              clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_TOKEN}
              render={(renderProps) => (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  className='bg-white flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none'
                  onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                  disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                >
                  <FcGoogle className='mr-4' />Sign in with Google
                </button>
              )}
              onSuccess={responseGoogle}
              onFailure={responseGoogle}
              cookiePolicy="single_host_origin" 
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

I think the problem is due to the if condition, but I added it after reviewing a Stackoverflow tab that suggested adding it as a null check, before adding it I was getting the error:

> Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj'

now the error is gone but it is not redirecting me to the home page (neither did it do so before the error). So where am I missing in my code exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution using jwt_decode (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode)
it is worked for me
[Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72278014/cannot-destructure-property-name-of-response-profileobj-as-it-is-undefined)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).